_MSC_VER value with multi Visual Studio installations
I have a C++ Project which uses boost libs, the project was built on MS visual studio 2019 using Boost_vc142_rev.1.79.
Now I moved to Visual Studio 2022 so I switched to boost_vc143_rev.1.85.
and every thing works fine.
I order to allow other them members with Visual studio 2019 to co-develop, I used the compiler directives to select which version of boost in included based in _MSC_VER.
#ifndef BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION
#if _MSC_VER >=1930     //Visual Studio 2022
#define BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION BOOST_WINAPI_VERSION_WIN10
#else
#define BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION BOOST_WINAPI_VERSION_WIN7
#endif

#if _MSC_VER >=1930     //Visual Studio 2022
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>

#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#else
#include <boost1_79/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost1_79/log/sinks.hpp>
#include <boost1_79/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost1_79/format.hpp>
#include <boost1_79/lockfree/queue.hpp>

#include <boost1_79/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include "boost1_79/multi_array.hpp"
#include <boost1_79/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#endif

I tested the compiler version used by both Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2022 using
cl /?

In the Developer Command prompt for each of them and found the value of 19.29.30154 & 19.40.33812 respectivly.
On Visual Studio 2019 I set the platform Toolset to v142.
But When I build on Visual studio 2019 I get the following error
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_log-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_85.lib'   my_lib  

Based on my code I expect that it will be linked with Boost 1_79
Note:On my machine I have Visual Studio 2017, 2019 and 2022.
I have not option to change MSVC Toolset Version other than Default and "14.29.30133"
How to overcome this problem
